# APNS not working anymore on PHP

Tags: php, ios, xcode, ubuntu, apple-push-notifications

The APNS service was working perfect a few days ago. The only thing that changed was that I upgraded my server from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04. After that upgrade my apns stop working. I don't know why but that is the only that I changed on my server.

I also tried to telnet gateway.push.apple.com:2195 with the certificate I generated from my mac And everything worked fine.

But when i try using my server with the php code I got this response:

**Failed to connect: 0**

```
          <?php

  // Put your device token here (without spaces):
  $deviceToken = 'bd218fb8ce00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

      // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    // Put your alert message here:
      $message = 'My first push notification!';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns.pem');
     stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

  // Open a connection to the APNS server
  $fp = stream_socket_client(
      'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 360, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

       // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => $message,
        'sound' => 'default'
        );

   // Encode the payload as JSON
 $payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

 if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
  else
  echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

 // Close the connection to the server
 fclose($fp);
```

Comment: make sure theat your pem file is reachable from your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After formatting and installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.10 everything went smoothly. APNS is working again like it is supposed.

Everything points that the upgrade mess up something on the PHP or any config files.

So the lesson is don't upgrade Ubuntu from the terminal.

Back up all your data first and Install a fresh version of Ubuntu from Disc or USB if you want to upgrade it. Reinstall LAMP with all updates possible and restore all your files and data.

Everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the correct  certificate path  in the php script i.e..

```
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',APPPATH.'../assets/apns.pem');
```